# executing bash script upon keyboard interrupt in python

Tags: python, bash, flask

I want to execute some bash script upon keyboard interrupt but it seems my python code is exiting without executing the bash script at keyboard interrupt.here is my sample code.

```
from flask import Flask
import os
#here resides my flask code

try:
   if __name__ == '__main__':
      app.run()
except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
    os.system('echo "running bash script from python"')
    os.system('netstat --listen')
    os.system('sudo service apache2 start')
    exit()
```

Comment: This is strange. I do not have this problem at all. Neither with Python 2 or 3. Is it a permissions issue?

Answer (score 0):

Upon thinking about this, I think your app might be capturing the KeyboardInterrupt and preventing the encapsulating script from ever getting the exception, by forcibly killing the process or something similar.  A minimal example that I could cook up which reproduces your issue is:

```
import os

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        while True:
            try:
                pass
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                os.kill(os.getpid(), 9)
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        os.system('echo "This will not be executed"')
```

Comment: the example you have given @Evey it's executing the bash script upon exit but it's only printing the message inside echo , but not starting the apache2 service though it's showing the message of service starting